# How to add reference with "copy local" true via roslyn?

Tags: .net, vb.net, roslyn

I am trying to add metadata reference to my VB.NET project via roslyn using the following syntax:

```
project = project.AddMetadataReference(
    MetadataReference.CreateFromFile(
        package.FullName,
        MetadataReferenceProperties.Assembly));
```

However, I need to set "Copy local" to `true` for this assembly, how to do that? Seems like for assembly reference I only have `WithEmbedInteropTypes` and `WithAliases` available, how to set the rest of properties of a particular reference...?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect that "copy local" is an MSBuild feature rather than a *compiler* feature. If you look at the `csc` command line:

```
                        - INPUT FILES -
 /recurse:<wildcard>           Include all files in the current directory and
                               subdirectories according to the wildcard
                               specifications
 /reference:<alias>=<file>     Reference metadata from the specified assembly
                               file using the given alias (Short form: /r)
 /reference:<file list>        Reference metadata from the specified assembly
                               files (Short form: /r)
 /addmodule:<file list>        Link the specified modules into this assembly
 /link:<file list>             Embed metadata from the specified interop
                               assembly files (Short form: /l)
 /analyzer:<file list>         Run the analyzers from this assembly
                               (Short form: /a)
 /additionalfile:<file list>   Additional files that don't directly affect code
                               generation but may be used by analyzers for produ
cing
                               errors or warnings.
```

You can do `/reference:<alias>=<file>` to get an alias, or `/link:<file list>` to embed interop metadata, but there's no option *here* to "copy local".

You'll have to perform the copy yourself.